# Android grid layout with unequal squares

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-custom-view, android-gridlayout

[image]I'm trying to create a layout consisting of square images in grid like collection with unequal sizes (**weights**) in android.
I found many grid layout libraries but none match my requirement.

I'm trying to acheive something as seen in this image

there are **no fixed columns or rows** here.and that's the main problem in using a grid layout.

is there any library available for this purpose?
If not, how can i achieve this using grid layout/recycler view.

Comment: You should create your own view to achieve like this

Comment: you can use Staggered layout manager with recycle view

Comment: @abdul couldn't find anything about scattered layout.Can you share a link?

Comment: sorry, it is staggered layout
https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Comment: but as i said, the staggered grid has fixed columns.But in image above the columns are not fixed as you can see

Comment: Use flexible layout https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout